# TCP IP Socket Client - Available Options?

Tags: sockets, tcp-ip

I deal with a lot of socket programming and I need a client that can connect to a listening server and be able to send both JSON and XML. 
Is there any software that is capable of that?

I tried telnet and each time I send some string it disconnects. Commandline tool is okay but I would prefer GUI if there is one

Comment: Netcat? It is `nc` command.

Comment: can it receive response and send text? example?

Answer (score 1):

```
nc <server> <port>
```

After that, everything that is typed in is sent. Data from server is printed.

To get more flexibility, make a fifo `mkfifo myfifo` and read from it:

```
tail -f myfifo | nc <server> <port>
```

Then from other terminal window the files can be sent:

```
cat myfile > myfifo
```